# SWIG wrapper undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, swig

I am trying to create a wrapper for C++ code to use it in a python project.
The code is taken from [here](https://github.com/erdavila/M-Tree/tree/master/cpp) (mainly `mtree.h`).

I am using swig for generating the interface by:
`swig -python -module mtree mtree.h`

then when I try `gcc -c -fpic mtree_wrap.c` I get the following error:

```
user@ubuntu:~/git/M-Tree/cpp2python(master)$ gcc -c -fpic mtree_wrap.c
mtree_wrap.c: In function ‘Swig_var_mt_set’:
mtree_wrap.c:3029:7: error: ‘mt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       mt = *((namespace *)(argp));
       ^~
mtree_wrap.c:3029:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
mtree_wrap.c:3029:15: error: ‘namespace’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘isspace’?
       mt = *((namespace *)(argp));
               ^~~~~~~~~
               isspace
mtree_wrap.c:3029:26: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
       mt = *((namespace *)(argp));
                          ^
mtree_wrap.c: In function ‘Swig_var_mt_get’:
mtree_wrap.c:3041:47: error: ‘mt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   pyobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(&mt), SWIGTYPE_p_namespace,  0 );
                                               ^
mtree_wrap.c:1163:89: note: in definition of macro ‘SWIG_NewPointerObj’
 ointerObj(ptr, type, flags)            SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj(NULL, ptr, type, flags)
                                                                        ^~~
mtree_wrap.c:3041:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_as_voidptr’
   pyobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(&mt), SWIGTYPE_p_namespace,  0 );
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and this is the `mtree.c` lines where the error occurs

```
SWIGINTERN int Swig_var_mt_set(PyObject *_val) {
  {
    void *argp = 0;
    int res = SWIG_ConvertPtr(_val, &argp, SWIGTYPE_p_namespace,  0 );
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res)) {
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res), "in variable '""mt""' of type '""namespace""'");
    }
    if (!argp) {
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ValueError, "invalid null reference " "in variable '""mt""' of type '""namespace""'");
    } else {
      mt = *((namespace *)(argp));
    }
  }
  return 0;
fail:
  return 1;
}


SWIGINTERN PyObject *Swig_var_mt_get(void) {
  PyObject *pyobj = 0;

  pyobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(&mt), SWIGTYPE_p_namespace,  0 );
  return pyobj;
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use c++ mode of swig, with `-c++` switch. But this won't do you any good. Swig cannot create a wrapper for template class. You need to create proper swg file and declare template specification that should be used in python. Like this:

```
%module strmtree;

//generate good wrapper for std::string -> python string
%include "stdstring.i"

%{
//include actualy header in wrapper
#include "mtree.h"
%}

//generate wrapper for class in this file,
//but since the class is template, it won't generate anything on it's own.
%include "mtree.h"

//declare template specialization for string and call it StrMTree.
//ideally you'll get StrMTree class in python
%template(StrMTree) mt::mtree<std::string>;
```

No idea what type normally should go to mtree template parameter. If you want mtree of python objects, then it's much more complicated... You'll probably want some kind of interface in C++, specialization of mtree with this interface, and then implementation if interface in python.